# React Router Components not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, router

I'm having an issue with react-router-dom, the components aren't showing up.
I have checked in package.json that react-router-dom is well installed, and it is as it is showing:

`"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",`

And here is my App

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./Home.js"
import More from "./More.js"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/more" element={<More/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I feel like im doing everything right as i also added this to my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But my components are still not showing up

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code in the snippet. Are there any errors? What debugging have you done? Stopped and restarted any development servers? Do `Home` or `More` render without issue on their own not on a route? Would it be possible for you to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: no errors, Home and More render without issue without the routers

Comment: Can you confirm the installed `react-router-dom` version by running `npm list react-router-dom` from the project's root directory and report back? Can you also confirm the version of React that you are using?

Comment: i runned i different command but i still installed react-router-dom with npm install --save react-router-dom

Comment: What does "i runned i different command" mean? I'm asking for you to check what version is *actually* installed.

Comment: My bad. Yes, I installed react-router-dom, I just used a different command: npm install --save react-router-dom
My react version is:  "react": "^17.0.2",

Comment: This should work, see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-meadow-ppkheg)

Comment: Sorry, I think there's still a misunderstanding. By running `npm list react-router-dom` it will report the version(s) that are installed. This is so we can verify you are using the correct component API/syntax.

Comment: oh okay sorry, one sec

Comment: i mean i specified the version used in the post: react-router-dom@6.3.0

Comment: That doesn't confirm (to us) what is really installed. That might only be what you *think* is installed.

Comment: okay, yeah so installed 6.3.0

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you try making a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue then? Other than the duplicate/nested router I don't see anything that would cause the routed components not to render. It'd be nice if we could run your code live.

Comment: okay, give me a moment please

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you can not render a router inside another router, and you have:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

wich is:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/more" element={<More/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Try to remove one of the routers

Comment: This is true. I didn't catch it, but if so then I'd expect OP to have an invariant error thrown since nesting routers is invalid in RRDv6.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't seem to be working for me, the components are still not showing

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the router (BrowserRouter) in the app.js. Keep the  in the index.js and the app will work.

App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./Home.js"
import More from "./More.js"
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/more" element={<More/>}/>
        </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```